# django/ajax CSRF token missing

Tags: ajax, django, jquery-select2

I have the following ajax function which is giving me a cross site forgery request token error once I get past the minimumlengthinput of 3 with the select2 control. Knowing this I attempted to add { csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' }, to my data:.  After adding the csrfmiddlewaretoken I'm still getting the CSRF token missing or incorrect error.  I believe it has something to do with the my function for the searchFilter and searchPage follows.  What is the proper way to do this?

```
// using jQuery
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.selectuserlist').select2({
      minimumInputLength: 3,
      allowClear: true,
      placeholder: {
        id: -1,
        text: 'Enter the 3-4 user id.',
      },
      ajax: {
        type: 'POST',
        url: '',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken },

        function(params) {
          return "{'searchFilter':'" + (params.term || '') + "','searchPage':'" + (params.page || 1) + "'}";
        },

        processResults: function (res, params) {
            var jsonData = JSON.parse(res.d);
            params.page = params.page || 1;
            var data = { more: (jsonData[0] != undefined ? jsonData[0].MoreStatus : false), results: [] }, i;
            for (i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
              data.results.push({ id: jsonData[i].ID, text: jsonData[i].Value });
            }

            return {
              results: data.results,
              pagination: { more: data.more,
              },
            };
          },
      },
    });

  });
```

My view has the POST method and csrf_token as well.

```
  {% block content %}
  <form action = "{% url 'multiresult' %}" form method = "POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
  {% block extra_js %}
      {{ block.super }}
      {{ form.media }}
```

The response from the console is

Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /search/multisearch/
[29/Mar/2018 09:14:52] "POST /search/multisearch/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2502

Comment: The Django docs explain how you can set a header [for ajax requests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#ajax). Since your ajax request submits json encoded data, you must use that approach.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to include the `csrf_token` as header:

```
var csrftoken = $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();

//example ajax
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    headers:{
        "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken
    },
    data: data,
    cache: true,
});
```

Also make sure that `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE` = `False` if you're not on ssl.
If you're using ssl set it to `True`.

> Whether to use a secure cookie for the CSRF cookie. If this is set to True, the cookie will be marked as “secure,” which means browsers may ensure that the cookie is only sent with an HTTPS connection.

Comment: Would I add the CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE to my settings.py?  I'm not using SSL.

Comment: Yes add it to the settings

Comment: I did what you suggested and it corrected my CSRF error.  My results are another issue, thanks for leading me in the correct direction.

Comment: No problem :) I am glad I was able to help

Comment: where is csrftoken? Django sucks.

Answer (score 3):

A mixture of JS and Django template language helped solve this.

```
  $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         headers:{
        "X-CSRFToken": '{{ csrf_token }}'
         }
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Just changed the line of code below, it is much simpler because you don't have to involve the template. The js snippet you provided already has the csrf value.

```
  data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' },
      // INTO
  data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken },
```

Comment: I've done as you suggested and i'm still running into the same problem of a 403 error.  I've added the change above.

Comment: Also, that 403 error occurs once the minimumlengthinput of 3 is met in the select2 control.