# send data using POST request in TemplateView Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm using `Django 2.0`

I have a `TemplateView` that renders only the template. Since the template is rendered using `ajax`, I have to send token using `POST` to `LearnQuestion` just to verify and there is no need of form.

I tried following

> Case 1:

**views.py**

```
class LearnQuestion(TemplateView):
    # form_class = SessionForm
    template_name = 'learn/learn_question.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LearnQuestion, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # get session data
        session = self.request.POST.get('session')
        print(session)
        context['session'] = session

        return context

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(self.__class__, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Ajaxrequest

```
<input id="session-d" value="{{ session }}" type="hidden">

$(window).on('load', function() {
    console.log($('#session-id').val())
    $('#question-box').load("{% url 'learn:question' course_learn.pk %}", {session:$('#session-id').val()}, function(){
        runTimer();
    });
});
```

But this gives error

```
Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /learn/q/63aa909f-ffb4-462e-bdcc-018bc71d35d2
```

> Case 2:

same view with `<form>` in template

```
<form id="sesion-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input id="session-d" value="{{ session }}" type="hidden">
</form>

$(window).on('load', function() {
    console.log($('#session-id').val())
    $('#question-box').load("{% url 'learn:question' course_learn.pk %}", $('#session-form').serializeArray(), function(){
        runTimer();
    });
});
```

This gives error

```
Method Not Allowed (POST): /learn/q/63aa909f-ffb4-462e-bdcc-018bc71d35d2
```

> Case 3:
>   changed `TemplateView` to `FormView` and created a form in **forms.py**

**forms.py**

```
class SessionForm(forms.Form):
    session = forms.CharField()
```

**views.py**

```
class LearnQuestion(FormView):
    form_class = SessionForm
    template_name = 'learn/learn_question.html'
    ...
    ...
```

But this gives error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: No URL to redirect to. Provide a success_url.
```

But I do not want a redirect url.

**How can I send `POST` request to `TemplateView` or use `FormView` without `redirect_url`?**

**I do not want form handler just want to send POST data using ajax to view**

Comment: Just a hint to improve your view: you can use the [`LoginRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) instead of `method_decorator`.

Comment: **You have to send token using POST just to verify and there is no need of form.** Where exactly you send that post request?

Comment: Lemayzeur, Sending that post request to `LearnQuestion`

Comment: Forms are for validation as well as display. They are still useful in Ajax.

Comment: Check out my answer for how to send an ajax request to the backend correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49694097/7707749 @AnujTBE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can pass `csrf_token` as `header` in ajax request as answered by @King Reload [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49694097/3719167)

```
headers:{
    "X-CSRFToken": '{{ csrf_token }}'
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the **csrf_token** by Javascript also, for sending it to POST requests by ajax.

```
// using jQuery
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

Now when you are sending the data by ajax you can use this csrftoken

```
var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
```

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#ajax